# TSQL query to end user

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have written a parameterized transact SQL query for a member of our finance department and several times during the month I run it and copy the raw output with headers into excel for him. Now that department is being regionalised and I've got several finance departments all wanting the same thing.

I know that SSRS will be deployed eventually but our infrastructure team are building a new environment and don't want any new installations in the 'old world' for the moment.

I just need a way to give select individuals access to run that parameterized query against the database. I had thought about turning the query into a view and creating logins for their network accounts with access only to that view but I don't think you can use parameters with views. I wondered if there is a simple interface that can allow them to enter parameters against a stored query or view without using SSRS. It seems so simple but I'm not having much luck finding out.

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I've just moved from server admin to a DBA role and I've only just scratched the surface!

Comment: create a view and called that in SP with Parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view and called that in SP with Parameter:-

Sample would be

```
Create View [dbo].[vw_sampleView]
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM tblSample
END


CREATE PROC [dbo].[proc_GetData]
@id int
AS    
BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM vw_sampleView where id= @id
END
```

Then this SP retunred filtered data.  Grant the permission to execute this SP to different users.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[proc_GetData] TO [user_logins]
```

Comment: AH ok, hadn't thought of using a SP. So create the view with the majority of the query and use the SP to so the parameterized part? I'd just need to play about with accessing SPs via excel as they won't have SSMS or Access.

Comment: right, or, if you dont want to create view, thats also fine, just add your query in SP directly

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [UDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191007(v=sql.105).aspx) which will return a table based on the parameters. For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnt_myfunction]( @id INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
        SELECT *
        FROM myTable
        WHERE id = @id
        );

DECLARE @id INT = 1;  

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnt_myfunction](@id);
```

Hope that helps.